# Err_connection_refused(localhost:3000) -- Android emulator - Meteor cordova app

Tags: android, meteor-cordova

I am facing an err connection refused on android emulator. I am running the app using meteor codrova. I am trying to run the app in localhost:3000 in the emulator.

I have set like below in **config.xml**:

I have followed the below the tutorial to execute the app:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BNhekNjJSKA

I have added the browser to the cordova and am able to run the app and see the output in the browser after running from console.

Here is the error am facing when I run the cordova meteor app with "cordova emulate android"

[image]

Can anyone please help me? am trying to solve this very badly from 24 hours!!!

Comment: <content src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/" />
    <access origin="*" />

Comment: Aren't you supposed to be using `meteor run android`? That YouTube video is somewhat old. Check out the official documentation

Comment: I am working on meteor Cordova apps, am using command "cordova emulate/build Android"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue, I just stopped the server and run the command "meteor run android-platform" and now am able to see my app on emulator.

Thank you for the help!!